# How Does In This Case findAllBy* works?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two domain class :

**DaySchedule**

```
class DaySchedule {
    Date Todaysdate
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    String task
    int priority 
    boolean completed
    static belongsTo = [ schedule : Schedule ]
}
```

**Schedule**:

```
class Schedule {
    Date date;
    static belongsTo = [ user : User ]
    static hasMany = [ daySchedules : DaySchedule ]
        static constraints = {
        date(blank:false)
        }
        String toString() {
              "Belongs to schedule"
    }
}
```

Now, when I query on `DaySchedule` class with `findAllByTaskIsNotNull()` I expect it to return all the `task` on `DaySchedule`, but instead I'm getting `"Belongs to schedule"` as my query result. Like this

```
def allTasks = DaySchedule.findAllByTaskIsNotNull()
//returns "Belongs to schedule"
```

If I go one step further, and query `allTasks` I'm getting all the `task`, as expected. Like this :

```
def expected = allTasks.task
println expected //prints all tasks!
```

I couldn't understand the behavior of `findAllByTaskIsNotNull()`. So my actual question is `findAllByTaskIsNotNull()` should return all the `task`, right? Why it is finding its appropriate `Schedule`?  Whats going on? Am I understood the concept wrongly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone out there to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understood the concept wrongly indeed.
Dynamic finders retrieve objects or lists of objects of the class they are being called on.

So, in your example, DaySchedule.findAllByTaskIsNotNull() will retrieve objects of type "DaySchedule".

"task" is just a String property of your DaySchedule class, and you defined a toString method in your Schedule class that returns "Belongs to schedule"... so that's what gets printed when you invoke a println on your results because that class actually belongs to DaySchedule, and there is no toString method on your DaySchedule class.

So if you want to have the task property displayed instead... just add this to your DaySchedule class :

```
String toString() {
     return this.task
}
```

Comment: Oh ya I have understood wrongly! Thanks for the answer... Your correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is flawed, because the `toString` method is INSIDE `static contraints` closure, so i won't be surprised you have some side effect in the toString call. Try to fix the code putting  `toString` outside of the closure and let me know

Moreover, just look the method name: findAll-->By<---TaskIsNotNull, it means it will find the DyaSchedule that have no null tasks, so the answer is ok.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I'm still getting the same answer as before.